# How to mock an inline function

Tags: go, go-testing

I am trying to mock a function using GoMonkey, but I found it failed because compiler will be inline this function when program compiles, so GoMonkey can't mock it.

So how can I mock this function or how can I mock a other member's private function?

Test Code Like this:

```
        patches := gomonkey.ApplyFunc(time.ParseInLocation, func(format string, timeStr string, cstSh *time.Location) (time.Time,error) {
            return time.Time{},errors.New("error")
        })
        defer patches.Reset()
        resp:= Example("")
        So(resp, ....)
```

mock function

```
...
t, err := time.ParseInLocation(format, timeStr, cstSh)
...
```

Comment: Stop that mocking crap. Mocking is a technique from Java/C#/PHP which _doesn't_ work well with Go.

Comment: 1. Don't use mocks. 2. Even if you do use mocks, use a proper mocking library, not GoMonkey.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the go compiler from inlining functions using the pragma `//go:noinline` though as per the previous replies I would avoid the use of mocking if it's at all possible.
In addition, use of these pragmas is also not a particularly good idea.